# Can I fit a 32-630 tire on a 20-622 rim?

Tags: tire, rims, compatibility

I know that the width difference might present problems later on, but if I understand correctly then it should be possible. The bike isn't meant to be used in high performance circumstances, just the city.

However, if I understand correctly, the tire would have a larger diameter than the rim. Is that likely to cause me much trouble?

tl;dr If I have a 32-630 tire and a 20-622 rim, can I make the combination work?

Comment: 630 not equal 622

Comment: No, you can't. But innertubes are a different story, since they can stretch quite a lot, unlike tires.

Comment: And, in case no one else says it, "NO!".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  The bead seat diameter (inner diameter) is different by 8 mm.  You cannot shrink a steel or Kevlar bead by 8mm, as they are designed not to stretch  or shrink (otherwise a clincher tire will roll off the rim in a corner).   You can try but the tube will burst out from the extra space.

The tire bead is what interfaces with the rim.

Comment: Aaaah, I think I got it now! Thanks, Rider_X.

Comment: @WalterVos - Read up on tire sizes -- [one of the best references available](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html).